# How to embed a Google Drive folder in my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I have a folder in Google Drive and I need to embed it on my website. I used this code:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0B-cjMH6T4IV5bzlkUmpTWkhQOTg#grid" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

When I click to a folder, the folder opens in a new page but I need it to open in the same page on my website.

Answer (score 0):

When you embed the iframe and you click on element, you're clicking on that link with its own attributes that was set by Google. Their "<a>" has the attribute that requires the link to open in a new window. I am not sure if you can change it on your google drive.